# Performance issue on toggle/untoggle rows of a gridview having 1000+ rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, gridview

**QUESTION:** I use `toggle()` in jquery on table rows to show the user only filtered data. When I need to "untoggle" the rows when the user removes all the filters, it takes around 3-4 seconds, which is unacceptable. How can I reduce it?

**BACKGROUND:**

I have a GridView in my .net project, which includes 1000+ data. No pagination I am allowed to use.

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgMenuItems" runat="server" ... >

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Caption">  
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Caption" runat="server" style="display:block;" Text='<%#Eval("Caption") %>'></asp:Label> 
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField> 
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Link">  
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Link" runat="server" style="display:block;" Text='<%#Eval("Link") %>'></asp:Label> 
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField> 
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LinkCaption">  
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_LinkCaption" runat="server" style="display:block;" Text='<%#Eval("LinkCaption") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField> 

</asp:GridView>
```

There is a textbox and search button above the gridview, so I can filter the table (via **jquery**) out using one value being checked in each column. An example, assume the table is like below:

```
ID  Caption   Link     LinkCaption
 1  Admin     mylink1  Admin-Main
 2  Category  myLink2  Allitems
 3  Reports   myLink3  Report-Administrator
```

Then:

- when I search the word "admin", it returns 1 and 3
- when I search the word 'item', it returns only 2
- when I search the word 'mylink', it returns all rows

etc...

This is my function filtering the table:

```
function FilterTable() {

                var textToSearch=document.getElementById('MainContent_txtSearch').value;

                var $rows = $("tbody tr").each(function (index) {
                    var trr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    var caption = (trr.find('td:nth-child(3)').text().trim());
                    var link = (trr.find('td:nth-child(4)').text().trim());
                    var linkCaption = (trr.find('td:nth-child(5)').text().trim());

                    if (!(caption.toLowerCase().includes(textToSearch.toLowerCase()) || link.toLowerCase().includes(textToSearch.toLowerCase()) || linkCaption.toLowerCase().includes(textToSearch.toLowerCase()))) {
                        trr.toggle();
                    }

                }); 
            }
```

There is also a "CLEAR" button, removes all the filters using the function:

```
function ClearFilter() {
                var $rows = $("tbody tr").each(function (index) {
                    var trr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    if (!trr.is(":visible")) {
                        trr.toggle();
                    }
                });
            }
```

ClearFilter() takes 3-4 seconds when my GridView includes 1000+ rows. Is there any better (faster) way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried using classes instead of `.toggle()`? e.g. `trr.addClass("hidden")`, then simply `$(".hidden").removeClass("hidden")` - not tested myself, so not sure how much speed decrease it may offer

Comment: @user7290573 omg, I can't believe I didn't think of this. Works really fast. Thank you! Add it as an answer, I'll select the correct one.

Comment: No problem! Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the `.toggle()` method, use CSS instead. Change:

```
trr.toggle();
```

to

```
trr.addClass("hidden");
```

That way, your `ClearFilter` function can be greatly simplified to:

```
function ClearFilter() {
    $(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");
}
```